# Floating exception of unit tests with InMemoryDb

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have unit (`XUnit`) test project with `InMemoryDatabase`

```cs
public class MyTestDbContext : MyDbContext
{
   public static MyTestDbContext CreateTestDbContext()
   {
      var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>
       .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
       .ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning))
       .Options;
       
       var context = new MyTestDbContext(options);
       
       context.EntitySet1.AddRange(...);
       context.EntitySet2.AddRange(...);
       ...
       context.SaveChanges();
       return context();
   }
}
```

Also i have several classes with unit tests(`[Fact]`) which uses this context, for example

```cs
public class MyTests
{
  protected readonly MyTestDbContext Context;

  protected MyTests()
  {
    Context = MyTestDbContext.CreateTestDbContext();
  }

  [Fact]
  private async Task MyTest()
  {
    // some code with Assert CRUD operations with Context
  }
}
```

What's problem. When i run tests first time (after unit test proj Clean And Rebuild for example) i get failed random tests with exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The entity type 'MyEntity1' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.
 ...
```

But when i run tests second time all test pass successfully.

Why it happens? How to fix it?

Comment: Do you have a full [mre]?